# How do I set security rules in Firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

How do I set security rules in Firebase realtime database?

I got this information.

> You choose to start development in test mode, which results in your Cloud Firestore database being fully published on the Internet. Your application is more vulnerable to attacks, so your Firestore security rules have been set to stop receiving any requests after the first 30 days have passed.

> The system will begin to reject all client requests sent to the Firestore database. Until then, please write high-strength security rules so that the application can operate normally while properly protecting your data. The system performs analysis tasks every day. If you have modified the rules in the past 24 hours, the analysis results may not reflect the changes.

my rules set

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null",
  }
}
```

in Realtime Database

[image]

so how should I do?

Comment: You have mentioned Cloud Firestore in your question but the rules and the screenshot are from Realtime Database. They are 2 different databases. Also the rules doesn't relate to time based access. Can you clarify which database are we talking about ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I got this information in my email, so is it mean I need to modify firebase realtime database or Cloud Firestore?

Comment: I'd guess it was about Firestore but it'll be best if you could share a screenshot of that email so we can check it .

Answer (score 0):

The backgroundinfo is not important to you, because you are using realtime database instead of firestore.

Firebase explains how to use rules for both Firestore and Realtime on their  [website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules). You must read the part about RealTimeDatabase and JSON-based rules

Comment: I have used real-time database, storage, and cloud message, so do I modify it?

Comment: Yes you should modify these rules.